# Get-childitem to sequentially rename files from different subfolders

Tags: command-line, powershell, rename

Windows system using Powershell.

I have 5 folders on my PC each containing 2 subfolders named images and json, each images subfolders has 3 png files
numbered 1.png, 2.png and 3.png. The json subfolders have the same structure with 3 files each 1.json, 2.json and 3.json.

What I'm doing is taking all .png files from all images subfolders and putting them in a single sequence, ie 1.png, 2.png,
3. png, 4.png, 5.png, 6.png,...

When I run the command to do this using the -whatif option, the files are in the correct sequence I want, but when
I run the command to generate the files, the first file in the subfolder 2 skips the sequence, see below:

Command executed in Powershell with -whatif option:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $i=1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-childitem -Path D:\Files_png_json\ -Recurse  -Filter *.png | foreach { rename-item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension ) -whatif}
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\1.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\1.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\2.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\2.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\3.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\3.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\1.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\4.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\2.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\5.png".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" in destination "Item: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\3.png Destination: D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\6.png".
```

Note, below, that png images generated in Subfolder 2 start with 5.png.

Names of files generated after the command without -whatif:

```
Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images\

15/03/2022  11:25    <DIR>          .
15/03/2022  11:25    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 1.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 2.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 3.png


Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images\

15/03/2022  11:53    <DIR>          .
15/03/2022  11:53    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 5.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 6.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 7.png
```

Why when I ran the command with the -whatif option it shows that in subfolder 2 the images will be generated with the correct sequence, 4, 5, 6.png and after i run the command, the images are generated from the number 5, 6 and 7.png?

Why did he skip the 4.png sequence and start with 5.png?

Comment: Add in the `-File` parameter to ensure you get only files. There is something funny about the `-filter` sometimes but I don't remember the specifics. So use `get-childitem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Recurse -File *.png -Filter | foreach {` or perhaps `get-childitem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Recurse -File *.png | foreach {` with your logic and see if that does it for you.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style Ok, but a question, how do I set the counter with the initial value = 1 when the file extension changes from png to json?

Comment: You would do a separate loop of `get-childitem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Recurse -File *.json -Filter | foreach { $i=1 } { rename-item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension ) }`. You can just set the `$i` to a `1` value in the begin block of a loop or just set it before you iterated and loop over the json extensions. The logic will get more complex if you are iterating over both .png and .json files in the same loop and want to keep the counters separate for each file extension. I'm not sure what that looks like that at the moment or how to make that happen.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style There is no way for me to put an "if" before renaming the files, so I would define at the beginning two different variables and depending on the "if" I would count with the respective extension variable. As I'm still learning Powershell, I don't know where I could put this "if" and which command to use for that.

Comment: All good, here's example logic for an idea but I did not test it. But to give you an idea of what is possible. `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Folder\" -Recurse -File *.json -Filter | foreach { 
    If ( $_.extension -ne $prevExt ) { $i=1 }
        Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension);
        $prevExt = $_.extension; 
        }` .... https://i.imgur.com/2b8i1gR.png .... This was should reset the count on null or a different value for `$prevExt` but just one quick idea of a possibility.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style Perfect, it worked... I will answer my question and put the correct command... only your suggestion of -File didn't work, but I found the solution for this. Thank you!

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style I'm trying to move the renamed files to two other folders: png and json, using -destination, but it gives error!... how do I move all the png to the png folder and the json to the json folder so that each of them be separated in different folders? Is there a way to make this command see the extension to write to the right folder and then move it to the folder? I tried -destination but it gave an error!

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests with the numbering of files skipping and found a solution. Replaces the -Filter command in the selection of files, the command working correctly is now:

```
'D:\Files_png_json\' | ForEach-Object{$($_ + "\*.png"), $($_ + "\*.json")} | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach { If ( $_.extension -ne $prevExt ) { $i=1 } Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension); $prevExt = $_.extension; }
```

Note:
Since my subfolders have two types of files, png and json, added "if" command to control file extension type so file name numbering resets from number 1 when extension changes:

eg. 1.png, 2.png, 3.png... 1.json, 2.json, 3.json...

thanks to @Vomit IT regarding this detail.

Output Changed command:

```
 Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Images

15/03/2022  11:25    <DIR>          .
15/03/2022  11:25    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 1.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 2.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 3.png
```

```
 Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Images

16/03/2022  17:38    <DIR>          .
16/03/2022  17:38    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 4.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 5.png
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 6.png
```

```
 Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 1\Json

16/03/2022  09:19    <DIR>          .
16/03/2022  09:19    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 1.json
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 2.json
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 3.json
```

```
 Folder of D:\Files_png_json\Folder 2\Json

16/03/2022  17:38    <DIR>          .
16/03/2022  17:38    <DIR>          ..
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 4.json
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 5.json
26/02/2022  18:49           276.772 6.json
```

Comment: You are welcome! Regarding the `-File` parameter thing, also do not use `-Filter` and do use `-File` though and see if that does that for you. Not sure what's up there otherwise with that.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style I'm trying to move the renamed files to two other folders: png and json, using -destination, but it gives error!... how do I move all the png to the png folder and the json to the json folder so that each of them be separated in different folders? Is there a way to make this command see the extension to write to the right folder and then move it to the folder?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this and I've done it before. It sounds similar to another post I've answered but I cannot find it for you to reference. I would suggest that you open a new question post with that question and show your logic, etc. that you are working with. Someone here should be able to help you figure it out. If I see it and have time later, I'll check it out too.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style hi, I wanted to know a detail: is the variable $prevExt being created at the time of the command?... in which place did it receive a value to be compared with the extension?

Comment: I thought about that too, I think we need to add in an `-or` operator to also check if the variable is null so the loop logic should probably look something like this to handle that.... `foreach { If ( $_.extension -ne $prevExt -or $prevExt -eq $null ) { $i=1 } Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}' -f $i++ +$_.extension); $prevExt = $_.extension; }`. Otherwise you can outside the loop before you start running it set it as `$prevExt = ""` and that should do it too. I was going to write you about this but didn't get a chance too the other day.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style, ok already changed, I opened another question as you said, regarding copying the files using this same command, it happens that when it goes to copy the renamed files, it informs that the file does not exist ! see at: https://superuser.com/questions/1711466/moving-renamed-files-to-folders-according-to-their-extension